# Get Facebook fan page-id in page tab app using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can I get Facebook fan `page-id` in page tab app without authorizing user using javascript? And also if I authorized user and after that I get `signed_request` which only contains

```
["algorithm","code","issued_at","user_id"] not "page" object. How can I get "page" object?
```

I want to add Page tab app similar to **Pinterest Page App**, which initially get `UserId`/`UserName` and after that if we open that app then it will directly open according to inserted `UserId`/`UserName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not.

The page info is send only in the signed_request that gets POSTed to your app so with JavaScript, you have no access to POST data. But you can easily access with server side language.

You might found a lots of PHP code for it..for C# you can use below code..

```
string signedR = Request["signed_request"];
```

I hope this might be helpful to you...@Mirant

Comment: Thanks Dipen for helping me out!! :)

Comment: Anytime budy..@Mirant

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get Facebook fan page-id in page tab app […] using javascript?

No, you can not.

The page info is send only in the `signed_request` that gets POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe – and with JavaScript, you have no access to POST data.

The `signed_request` you get from the JavaScript SDK is a “different one”, it contains info about the auth status and user only, not about the page.

> I want to add Page tab app similar to Pinterest Page App, which initially get UserId/UserName and after that if we open that app then it will directly open according to inserted UserId/UserName.

I don’t understand what you mean by that exactly. And I don’t see what this has to do with the page id, when you are only speaking of the user id/user name here?

Comment: @CBroe I do not understand why my question was marked as a duplicate, when this question has nothing to do with what I need!

Comment: This has everything to do with [your duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36140505/1427878). See my comment there please. (No need to drag the discussion out there.)