# Create new Page Tabs facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've looked everywhere but I could not find what I want. In my application I want to add that people can add to their Facebook pages containing a tab with my site. I have seen on other pages such as those pages where you can create events and sell tickets, then add the tab that event and appears on your facebook page. My idea is to do the same, but I find that in my facebook application add Page Tab URL can define a single that loaded inside the tab

Same with the name, I can not rename depending on what is shown on the tab. I wonder if this is possible and the SDK javascript or jquery.

I have the following code:

```
echo '<center><div>'.
    $this->Html->image('fb-icon-transparente.png', array('title'=>utf8_encode("Facebook Tabs"),'style'=>'width: 103px;margin-top: 23px;', 'id' => 'facebook_tab'));
echo '</div>';

 $("#facebook_tab").click(function(){
    var obj = {
        method: 'pagetab',
        display: 'popup',
    };
    FB.ui(obj, function(response) {
        console.log(response);  
    });
 });
```

I tried with parameters, I have also read the documentation but can not find anything about it, but if you've seen other pages do.

[image: facebook page tab]

Comment: Since you asked why this was closed as a duplicate: As explained in the answer over there, the way to get the id of the page that the tab is shown on, is to decode the `signed_request` parameter that gets POSTed to your app. You can not do this client-side via JavaScript, because POST data is only available to the server. And this is the only way to do it – you can not specify different URLs.

Comment: As last thing, then it is for Facebook issues that can not specify different URLs for tabs? always be the same URL, right? I did not need the id of the page, but I think if you tell me this has a little sense not being able to change the url of the tab. @CBroe

Comment: No, you can not specify different page tab URLs for one single app. If you want to display content based on what page the app is running on, then use the page id. That’s all there is.